# PHP: Preg_match_all escape round brackets

Tags: php, preg-match

i have dynamic string like this:

```
$string1 = '<a style="background-image: url(&quot;http://someurl.com/image.jpg&quot;);" class="thumb" title="title goes here" href="http://www.someurl.com/"></a>';
```

my preg_match_all code:

```
preg_match('/<a style="background-image: url((.*?));" class="thumb" title="(.*?)" href="(.*?)"><\/a>/', $string1, $matches);

echo $matches['1'];
echo $matches['2'];
echo $matches['3'];
```

the url() bracket is not working, any idea how to escape that?

Comment: `\\` would be the typical escape character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Regex with parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220180/php-regex-with-parentheses)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `(`,`)` with `\`:

```
preg_match('/<a style="background-image: url\((.*?)\);" class="thumb" title="(.*?)" href=" (.*?)"><\/a>/', $string1, $matches);
```

As a general rule, using regex to parse an HTML page isn't the way to go. see [Parsing Html The Cthulhu Way](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).
There are plenty of examples here on SO for better solutions.