# PHP preg_match check for parentheses

Tags: php, web, calculator

I am currently working on trying to create a calculator in PHP that will take the input of one whole string, after that I have it identify which part of the string contains the math problem and then I am using `eval()` to solve the problem. My goal is to make a conditional that will allow for the part that has the math problem to only have numbers, white space and the necessary characters for the basic math. My problem is that I can't figure out how to check for parentheses.

Here is my code:

```
if (preg_match("/^\s*([-+]?)(\d+)(?:\s*([-+*\/])\s*((?:\s[-+])?\d+)\s*)+$/", trim($input, " "))){
  $output = eval("echo " . $input . ";");
}else{
  echo "You entered an invalid input";
}
```

I would highly appriciate any help I can get. Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't appear you are checking for parentheses; where do you want to check for them?

Comment: I don't know how to check for them, I would like to check for them in the preg_match() function.

Comment: Yes, but specifically which part of the regex do you wish to check them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Regex with parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220180/php-regex-with-parentheses)

Comment: The parentheses can be in any part of the input.

Comment: so just put them in your character class(es) (eg. `[-+)(]`)... If outside of that then you'll want to escape them (eg. `\(, or \)`)...

Comment: I'm really new to this whole concept and I had someone else write the code that worked with everything above in it. I would appreciate it if you could show me exactly where that goes. Thanks